# Using Apache Superset and Google Sheets, how to check that the value is not null, as well as add other conditions?

Tags: google-sheets, google-visualization, apache-superset

I'm using **Apache Superset** to retrieve data from **Google Sheets**. [Shillelagh](https://shillelagh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) is used for integration with Google Sheets.

I have a column which specifies a deadline for tasks. If the task doesn't have a deadline, the field is empty.

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Deadline |
| 1 | 1-Jan-2022 |
| 2 | 1-Jan-2021 |
| 3 |  |

The problem occurs, when I try to filter dates by this column.
The query looks something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/****"
WHERE Deadline is not NULL AND Deadline < date('2021-12-31')
```

If I write each part of the query separately, it works:

- `WHERE Deadline is not NULL` --> Returns rows 1 & 2
- `WHERE Deadline < date('2021-12-31')` --> Returns row 2 & 3

The problem occurs when I try to use both of these conditions, so I would only get the tasks that have deadline specified & the deadline was missed (row 2):

- `WHERE Deadline is not NULL AND Deadline < date('2021-12-31')` --> This returns `gsheets error: No valid filter found`

I made sure that the data in the spreadsheet is date or null. Superset recognizes the column as a DATETIME type.

I'm at a loss why this is not working when combined. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What does this have to do with SQLite and Python?

Comment: @forpas They are required by the library (Shillelagh) that makes the DB/SQL connection with Google Sheets (as I understood the linked docs)

Comment: Try replacing `'now'` by  `'2021-12-31'` -> `WHERE Deadline is not NULL AND Deadline < date('2021-12-31')`

Comment: @Rubén My apologies. When I edited the answer for clarity, I forgot to edit that part. The error is the same in both cases.